# Firebase Security Rule clarification

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to set security rules for accessing my Firebase database from a react native project. I currently have a root path `tasks/` and within it are pushed task items. Each task has 3 children, the important one being the uid field that is populated with the user id when the user creates a task. Here is a sample task that would be located at `tasks/randomtaskid`:

```
{
  "date" : "2017-12-11",
  "ttRef" : "irrelevant",
  "uid" : "DrL3j1cWVehas45ghmeQ"
}
```

I am trying to use the security rules to restrict read / write access to any task, only allowing users to create tasks with their own UIDs and read / query tasks that match theirs.

Here are my security rules regarding the tasks portion of my database:

```
"tasks": {
    ".indexOn": ["uid", "date"],
    "$task": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['date', 'ttRef', 'uid'])",
        ".write": "auth != null && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
        ".read": "auth != null && data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
  },
},
```

The security rules simulator says that this does restrict access successfully - when I try to read / write to a task that doesn't match the uid it blocks access and it allows it when it does match, but when I attempt to access tasks from within my app, I get a permission denied error (that goes away once I go back to allowing all authenticated users read / write access to `tasks/`). Why would they be different and what can I do to fix my rules? Thanks!

Edit: code example that causes error:

```
firebaseRef.database().ref('tasks/').orderByChild('uid').equalTo(u).once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
      var dates = [];
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          dates[dates.length] = child.val().date;
      });
      resolve(dates);
  });
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [minimum code that triggers the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry I didn't include that, I have edited it

Comment: The Firebase Database enforces security when you attach them. When you attach a listener to `/tasks`, it will only allow that when you have read access to `/tasks `. Since you don't have access to `/tasks`, the read is rejected. This means that security rules cannot be used to filter data, which is commonly referred to within Firebase as [rules are not filter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters). I suggest you read a few of the [previous questions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, this is the conclusion I came to as well once I dug into it a little more last night.